# CodeIgniter return data from controller

Tags: php, ajax, json, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter for a project I'm working on.

I have an ajax call in a view like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'extra/search/infojson/' + $(this).text().replace(/\s/g, "+");
    success: function(data) {
        /* Do something with that data */
    }

});
```

`infojson` is a method in a controller that takes a parameter of 'username', does a search, and will return a JSON object.  Is there any way I can return this data without having to create another view for it?  This method will only be used to return such data from this one page, so I can't see why I need to create another view just for that.  I've read about `_output()` but it didn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are compressing the output in your configuration file try to set `$config[‘compress_output’] = FALSE;`

Answer (score 4):

This was the answer:

Put `$this->config->set_item('compress_output', FALSE);` just before the echo to disable output compression.

Source: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/155810/#784452

Comment: a different way of my answer :)

Comment: @Deepak: The advantage Steve's anwser is that you can leave by default the compression on and disable when necessary, where using your anwser would mean no compression anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

**Of course.**

Return the data using PHP's `json_encode()` function, there is no need to call `$this->load->view('someview', $data);` to send data back to the browser on ajax requests.

```
class Extra extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function search($username){
        $results = your_search($username);
        echo json_encode(array("results" => $results));
    }
}
```

And your jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'extra/search/infojson/' + $(this).text().replace(/\s/g, "+");
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.results){
            /* Do something with the results */
        }
    }
});
```